# Why is router undefined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I was trying to modify this project from : https://github.com/coffcer/vue-chat .

I want to have another page which is used to log in , so I add another component(vue) and use `vue-router` to do this. Here are my steps:

1. Add a dependency(`vue-router`) in `package.json` :

```
   "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.0.0",
    "vue": "^1.0.0",
    "vuex": "^0.8.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6"

  }
```

2. Create a file named `router.js`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";


import chat from "components/chat";


Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path:"/chat",
        component: chat
    }
]

var router =  new VueRouter({
    routes
})
export default router;
```

3. In `main.js`:

```
// polyfill
import 'babel-polyfill';

import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import store from './store';

import router from "./router.js"


Vue.config.devtools = true;


const ins = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: { App },
    store: store,
    render: h => h(App)
});

console.log(router)
console.log(ins)
console.log(ins.$router)
```

At last, I can see the instance of `router` and `ins` , but
 `console.log(ins.$router)` throws an exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_router' of undefined
    at Vue.get (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:3313), <anonymous>:1250:52)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:1051), <anonymous>:36:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:1051)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:556)
    at fn (build.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:588)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:556)
    at build.js:579
    at build.js:582
```

The return of Vue in the console:

```
Vue {$el: div#app, $parent: undefined, $root: Vue, $children: Array(1), $refs: {…}, …}
$data: Object
$router: [Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property '_router' of undefined at Vue.get (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/dist/build.js:3313:2), <anonymous>:1250:52) at Vue.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:1:142)]
$route: [Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property '_route' of undefined at Vue.get (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/dist/build.js:3313:2), <anonymous>:1254:52) at Vue.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:1:142)]
$el: div#app
$parent: undefined
$root: Vue {$el: div#app, $parent: undefined, $root: Vue, $children: Array(1), $refs: {…}, …}
$children: [VueComponent]
$refs: {}
$els: {}
_watchers: []
_directives: [Directive]
_uid: 1
_isVue: true
_events: {hook:attached: Array(1), hook:detached: Array(1)}
_eventsCount: {}
_isFragment: false
_fragmentEnd: null
_fragmentStart: null
_fragment: null
_vForRemoving: false
_isBeingDestroyed: false
_isAttached: true
_isReady: true
_isDestroyed: false
_isCompiled: true
_unlinkFn: ƒ ()
_context: undefined
_scope: undefined
_frag: undefined
$options: {directives: {…}, elementDirectives: {…}, filters: {…}, transitions: {…}, components: {…}, …}
_data: {__ob__: Observer}
$store: Store {_getterCacheId: "vuex_store_0", _dispatching: false, _mutations: {…}, _rootMutations: {…}, _modules: {…}, …}
_propsUnlinkFn: null
__proto__: Object
```

How should I solve this?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't imported your App component in main.js file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from "./App.vue"
import router from "./router"

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

and make sure you App component have the `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>` tag

Comment: Thanks, I have already imported it, Still not work .The question has been updated.